# Save all open windows/tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser

Is there any way in Firefox, or any browser for that matter to save all open tabs/windows to disk?

I don't mean to save the state of windows and tabs I have open, bur rather to automatically save all pages to disk as files.

Is there any extension, or innate capability in any browser?

Comment: Do you want to do this automatically by selecting sites to save to disk or manually?

Comment: Automatically....I have about 60 tabs open, and just want a local offline copy of them all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mozilla Archive Format](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/212/?src=api) together with [Multiple Tab Handler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/4838/) can do this.

Comment: I am trying this out, but when I choose save all tabs it only ever seems to save the tab that I have open?

Comment: Works fine for me on FF 3.6.12. Make sure you have both installed. Right click on the tab bar, save tabs as.

Comment: do you have to select all the tabs first? Is there any way to switch the current live versions with the new save versions?

Comment: What I want is a way to beef up and ensure work offline mode works

Comment: This answer would be much better if it explained how to do it with those plugins...

Comment: @TomášZato The user hasn't been online since 2012, so if you know how to use the mentioned extension, you could propose an edit to the post to improve it for future readers.